# How to filter collection in linq based on some subobjects in that list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get only those employees that have at least one service, and which that service is  younger than current date (dt)

I tried with `.Any()` but it returns me all employees with all services (it doesnt check that date)

```
var employees =
  employeeService.GetAllActiveEmployeesForCompanyForLocation(companyId, location.Id)
    .Where(x => x.IsCounter && x.Services != null && x.Services.Count > 0 &&
                x.Services.Any(u => u.ActiveTo >= dt.Value));
```

I want to filter just those employees which have at least one service or more where ActiveTo is not in the past (dt is a current datetime.now)

Comment: dt.Value is just a date without hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: it looks ok, you can remove the count > 0, it is checked deu .Any(), maybe something with the dates or you filters already by date into  GetAllActiveEmployeesForCompanyForLocation(companyId, location.Id)

Comment: Its DateTime? Nullable prop

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple `.Where` and `.Select` statements after one another. Your LINQ query is very hard to read without more specific information about your objects.

To make it more readable, I would suggest splitting your requirements into separate queries, like so:

```cs
var employeesWithActiveServices = 
    employeeService.GetAllActiveEmployeesForCompanyForLocation(companyId, location.Id)
        .Where(e => e.IsCounter && e.Services.Count >= 1)
        .Select(e => e.Services.Contains(s => s.ActiveTo >= DateTime.Now)).ToList();
```

Notice how I removed your `e.Services != null` check. It is redundant when you're already checking `e.Services.Count`.

This was made quickly of the top of my head, so you may need to tweak it to suit your needs.

It is still a hard LINQ query to read without seeing the objects it is querying, but this at least makes the query itself more readable.

Comment: "Notice how I removed your e.Services != null check" - if the Services are null what happens

Comment: If `Services` is null, the `e.Services.Count >= 1` will return false as well, meaning that employee will not be included

Comment: You're right, I thought it would return NullRefferenceExc ... ;)

Comment: this is not correct answer..Im getting Ienumarable<Ineumarable> list in list..not good

Comment: I haven’t had the time to test this, like I said maybe it requires a tweak or two. Perhaps omitting the `.ToList()` might help

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any additional `null`, `Count` checks, otherwise SQL will be complex and slow:

```cs
var employees =
  employeeService.GetAllActiveEmployeesForCompanyForLocation(companyId, location.Id)
    .Where(x => x.IsCounter && 
                x.Services.Any(u => u.ActiveTo >= dt.Value));
```

EF Core translates your query into the SQL, which do not have NullReference exception.

Comment: "EF Core translates your query into the SQL, which do not have NullReference exception" - that is also true, even SqlCommand do not returns nullable collection, but i can`t determinate that by the given code example.